# Multiple update methods in same controller Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am currently trying to build a user registration system with edit fields. At the edit portion, I had to create separate views for editing/updating personal details, email, and passwords.

I started with an empty resource controller. it had only one edit method. Hence I added additional edit methods. Each method can have a separate route. However, I have a hard time having a separate route for each update method in each section as the resource has only one route like this in docs:

> PUT/PATCH /photos/{photo} update  photos.update

Is there any workaround for this?

**Controller**

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('users.index');
    }

    public function edit_personal(User $user)
    {
        $user_profile = User::find($user->id);

        return view('users.edit.personal', ['users' => $user_profile]);
    }

    public function update_personal(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        // How to write route for this method.
    }

    public function edit_email(User $user)
    {
        $user_profile = User::find($user->id);

        return view('users.edit.email', ['users' => $user_profile]);
    }

    public function update_email(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        // How to write route for this method.
    }

    public function edit_password(User $user)
    {
        $user_profile = User::find($user->id);

        return view('users.edit.password', ['users' => $user_profile]);
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/users/{user}/personal', 'UserController@edit_personal')->name('users.personal');
Route::get('/users/{user}/email', 'UserController@edit_email')->name('users.email');
Route::get('/users/{user}/password', 'UserController@edit_password')->name('users.password');
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

Basically I have separated edit portion of user controller into personal, email and password sections and they have separate forms. I want to write update functions for each section in UserController.

Comment: So you want to have different methods but you want the routes to be the same?

Comment: No. There is already a default route with url: users/{user}/. If I add the new route to second update method, that will also have same url since I cannot change url syntax. What I fear is that will the url for second method may invoke default update method or not. Please forgive me if I'm too dumb

Comment: So you need to pass one field as section or status like which portion you want to update in your body part and you can call same method and same route with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't know why are you using separate forms for updating each fields while you can do it in a  single form. however you can use either put/patch or post method for updates. here's i am using post for example.
routes:

```
Route::get('users/{user}/personal', 'UserController@edit_personal')->name('users.personal');
Route::post('users/{user}/personal', 'UserController@update_personal')->name('users.update-personal');
Route::get('users/{user}/email', 'UserController@edit_email')->name('users.email');
Route::post('users/{user}/email', 'UserController@update_email')->name('users.update-email');
Route::get('users/{user}/password', 'UserController@edit_password')->name('users.password');
Route::post('users/{user}/password', 'UserController@update_password')->name('users.update-password');
```

as you are using route model binding you can directly get the object.

```
public function edit_personal(User $user)
    {
        return view('users.edit.personal', ['users' => $user]);
    }

public function update_personal(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        //validation goes here
        $user->update([
            'value' => $request->value,
            ........... 
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I don't understand the concept. In docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers) it is stated that update action should have url: /users/{user} . But your route url is different (users/{user}/personal). Then how does it work.

Comment: the resource route for update is `users/{user}` but when you are defining your own route you can make it as you wish.